# Password for recovery mode

Tags: recovery-mode, clockworkmod-recovery, data-recovery

how to put a password to enter android recovery mode? I want to have high security so that no one formats my phone without a password even in recovery mode.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to add a custom lock for the recovery and/or bootloader?](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/62210/how-to-add-a-custom-lock-for-the-recovery-and-or-bootloader)

Answer (score 2):

You can't protect your recovery with a password.
It's  useless because if someone has physical access to your phone, he could just boot into download/bootloader/fastboot mode and flash a custom recovery to bypass any security on your phone.
This is also the reason why no recovery offers password protection.

Comment: There's no reason that the bootloader couldn't require a password, though.  The problem is that I'm not aware of an Android bootloader which supports such a thing :/