# Do devices with a fingerprint scanner secure access to the bootloader/recovery

Tags: security, bootloader

Pretty simple question but as I have never owned a device with a fingerprint scanner... basically I was wondering:

**If you secure your device with your fingerprint - is it possible to access the bootloader or recovery without it?**

I have tried searching but did not come up with any results answering my question. I'm asking because I thought it would be kind of clever to secure the bootloader and the recovery. If your device gets stolen / you loose it, then the thief/finder could not flash a fresh rom/firmware onto your device making the device useless for him.

**If the bootloader and the recovery can't be secured like this - do you know why?**

Thanks for your feedback!

Comment: Did you read [how to add a custom lock for the recovery and/or bootloader?](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/62210)

Comment: @Firelord yes I stumbled across it a few hours ago but maybe things have changed with the new security possibilitys these days :) - thanks anyways

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In answer to your first question, I'd say yes. If there was a serious error with the fingerprint sensor hardware or a glitch with the software, you'd need to somehow recover your device. And if something isn't working, then where are you left?

And in answer to the second question - the fingerprint software is pretty high-level and out of fastboot's (the general Android bootloader. Samsung use another one, called Odin) control really, however I guess it could be implemented if it's necessary. However, it would also be unnecessarily complicated to implement this in the bootloader, and would require quite a lot of communication between both fastboot and the Android system whenever the device gets turned on to make sure both software layers use the same fingerprints, etc.

I do see your point with protecting recovery with a fingerprint - TWRP is Linux based and so could theoretically support it, but then someone could simply overwrite it with a stock recovery image.